# Triple Integral, Volume of an Egg

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I need to find the volume of an egg with a shape described by:

$$z = \frac{1}{2}(x^2 + y^2) \text{ and } z = 6 - x^2 - y^2$$

I am also given that the egg is $6$ cm in length.

I roughly graphed the two surfaces. The first being paraboloid that opens up from the origin, and the second being a paraboloid that opens down from $z =6$. The region under these two surfaces is the "egg."

How do I set up a triple integral to evaluate the volume of this region?

Answer (score 0):

Find where they meet each other, e.g.
$$6-x^2-y^2 = \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2).$$
Write this as a triple integral whose limits in $z$ are the inferior paraboloid and the superior paraboloid. The region you'll be integrating in the $xy$ plane is the circle you find at their intersection.

Comment: Yes, the intersection makes a circle with eq. x^2 + y^2 = 4, correct? Then integrate dz from z = 1/2(x^2+y^2) to z = 6 - x^2 - y^2. And I would integrate my circle in polar coordinates from 0 to 2 and 0 to 2pi, correct?

Comment: @user3681755 Yes.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user3681755 Consider accepting it if it helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using cylindrical coordinates:

$z=\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)=6-x^2-y^2 \implies x^2+y^2=4$

**Volume** $\displaystyle=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2}\int_{\frac{1}{2}r^2}^{6-r^2}rdzdrd\theta=12\pi$